# Write modified text selection to Clipboard

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm trying to wrap a text selection in quotes, and write this to the clipboard, but am having difficulty getting the script to copy it. There are numerous examples online but most are a half-decade old or more and don't seem to work in modern browsers due to security reasons.

I'm wondering if it is still possible to do this, and it's not working because I'm trying to use this in a bookmarklet, or if this functionality is now disabled in current browsers for security reasons, to avoid clipboard poisoning.

Currently, I'm grabbing selected text, modifying it, writing it to an element, but then it never copies to the clipboard, even though there should be a click event from firing the bookmarklet.

**Example code:**

```
javascript: (function() {
  function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
      text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
      text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
  }

  function wrapText(t) {
    return '“' + t + '”';
  }

  function ModifiedTxt2Clipboard(t) {
    var node = document.createElement("tmptextarea");
    node.textContent = t;
    document.body.appendChild(node);
    document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    node.select;
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    document.body.removeChild(node);
  }

  ModifiedTxt2Clipboard(wrapText(getSelectionText()));
})();
```

Comment: I would advise you to consider more reliable tools for web automation than bookmarklets. As an example, the free extensions such as ['iMacros for Firefox'](http://wiki.imacros.net/Firefox) or ['iMacros for Chrome'](http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Chrome) (there's already a built-in clipboard variable). Related Q&A's on 'stakoverflow' are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imacros).